# What is the meaning of "package" keyword in C?

Tags: c

I recently came across the C function with return type as `void` and `package` keyword added in front of it.

Could anyone please tell me what the meaning of `package` in the below mentioned C function prototype represents?

```
package void function (void)
```

The macro definition for the package:

```
/* function and variable scope modifiers */ 

#define package //accessible within package only,used for functions only
```

Comment: its a gcc compiler and version is 4.8.2

Comment: The macro `package` is defined to be nothing, so it's a complete [no-op](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-op).  I can't imagine why anyone would do such a terrible thing.

Comment: @Rufflewind: Presumably it's for documentation purposes. It expresses, but does not enforce, some restriction on how the function is meant to be used. It could make some sense (if and only if the term "package" is defined somewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the information you want to communicate to the reader in a declaration differs from the information that C *lets* you communicate.

For example, C's use of the `static` keyword can be confusing. On an object declaration at block scope, it affects the storage duration of the object; on an object declaration at file scope (outside any function body), it affects the linkage.

Programmers will sometimes try to extend the language, by defining macros that more clearly express the intent.

For example, I might write:

```
#define PUBLIC extern
#define PRIVATE static

PUBLIC void func1(void);
PRIVATE void func2(void);
```

As far as the compiler is concerned, this is exactly equivalent to:

```
extern void func1(void);
static void func2(void);
```

but it *might* be clearer to a human reader who happens to know, or can guess, what the `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE` macros are supposed to mean.

In your case, you have:

```
#define package //accessible within package only,used for functions only
```

so `package` is replaced by nothing. (IMHO it would have been better to define `PACKAGE`, so it's obvious to a reader that this is a macro), followed by:

```
package void function (void);
```

The word `package` is ignored by the compiler. It's intended to convey to the human reader that the function `function` is intended to be "accessible within package only" -- whatever that means.

The C language does not have the concept of a "package". The largest unit of organization for a C program is the *translation unit*, consisting of a source file along with anything it `#include`s, directly or indirectly.

The author of the code presumably had something in mind as the definition of a "package". Perhaps it's some well-defined collection of translation units -- in which case there is no C syntax to express the restriction that the author intends.

One problem with this kind of thing is that although `package` *looks* like it could be a keyword, it's not enforced by the compiler. Perhaps there's another tool that checks the source files for "correct" use of `package` -- or perhaps it's entirely up to the maintainers of the code to use it correctly.

Without knowing what a "package" is, it's impossible to be sure what the `package` pseudo-keyword is supposed to mean. I *hope* that the term is precisely documented somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Keith. So the function should be accessed only with in the file scope. Since package is defined with nothing, this function will get treated as local function.

Comment: @user3395194: No. If the function is declared in a header file, the declaration is visible to any translation unit that `#include`s that header. Functions have *external linkage* by default. (In my opinion, it would have been better for them to have *internal linkage* by default, with a keyword required to provide external linkage, but that's not going to change.) Whatever `package` is supposed to mean, it will not be enforced by the compiler or linker.

Answer (score 4):

`package` is not a [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword) in any C standard.

Perhaps it's being `#define`d by some header file you're not showing us.

*Edit:* `package` is being defined to nothing, so it has exactly zero effect in your program. Maybe if you told us what this header file was, and what this other code is you're trying to use, we might understand why it exists.

Answer (score 2):

It can be a way for the author (programmer) to give the reader (maintenance programmer) some extra information about intentions and structure. From the comment "accessible within package only,used for functions only" it could also be defined as:

```
#define package static
```

Now all functions with "package" will be declared as static and have scope only within the "package" (source module/file). I see many programmers do things like this. Of course there is no standard for it so every time I have to find it out again "what's he doing?"